# Java 8 to 11 error - NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class sun.security.pkcs.SignerInfo

Tags: java, java-8, java-11

I'm migrating Java code repository from Java 8 to Java 11 and my application keeps failing due to the following error.

I tried searching for the solution online, but didn't find any help resources unfortunately.

Have anyone encountered the same, and if so, would you please point me in the right direction?

Error:

```
ERROR o.s.boot.SpringApplication               Application run failed java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class sun.security.pkcs.SignerInfo
                at java.base/sun.security.pkcs.PKCS7.parseSignedData(PKCS7.java:365)
                at java.base/sun.security.pkcs.PKCS7.parse(PKCS7.java:160)
                at java.base/sun.security.pkcs.PKCS7.parse(PKCS7.java:128)
                at java.base/sun.security.pkcs.PKCS7.<init>(PKCS7.java:110)
                at java.base/sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.<init>(SignatureFileVerifier.java:123)
                at java.base/java.util.jar.JarVerifier.processEntry(JarVerifier.java:308)
                at java.base/java.util.jar.JarVerifier.update(JarVerifier.java:239)
```

thanks.

Comment: The only thing in initialization of SignerInfo that looks likely to fail is getting DisabledAlgorithmConstraints for JAR. Check the java.security file in your JRE (for j9 up it is in JRE/conf/security) and make sure the setting of jdk.jar.disabledAlgorithms is valid.

Comment: A `NoClassDefFoundError` like this usually occurs after an exception was thrown while initializing the class. Look earlier in the log for an `ExceptionInInitializerError`, that should tell you the actual cause.